# Create custom open graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Here's the scenario, when you post a link to Facebook, the scraper makes an open graph story based on og tags. However, I woudl like to know if it's possible to change the image retrieved by the scraper with one loaded by the user.

Imagine it like this, I want to post a link but the referenced site has no image, I'd like to modify the story so that its image is one I upload manually. Is that possible?

Comment: Use Feed dialog, or publish via API - both ways allow to specify the thumbnail image via parameter (certain limitations apply, see docs.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in the API as suggested by CBroe. To clarify, I'm posting to a page, not to a profile, so I used the parameter link to, obviously, specify the link I was sharing. I also used the parameter picture to replace the thumbnail the scraper fetches with one I wanted.

This picture is a url, not an uploaded file, if someone is wondering.

So, the final array that will be sent to Facebook's API looks like this:

```
$data = ['message' => 'your message', 'link' => 'your-link.com', 'picture' => 'url/to/image.jpg'];
```

As I said, this will post a link to a page and replace the thumbnail fetched from Facebook's scraper with the image specified in the picture parameter.

Hope this helps anyone else with the same question :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correct understood your question.

FB takes image from OG tag, no other way, also you cannot change this tag dynamically. I faced a long time ago with problem, that **scraper** could not find image on dynamically generated page. The solution was - send to FB another permament link. For example - permament link on main page site.com/module, this page for sharing to FB site.com/module/?c=123123123 (generated page by user, $c - here uniq parameter which was responsible for image in OG tag)

So - anyway if want to share page with picture - it should be contained in OG tags.